# Files editing with shell scripting

Tags: shell

I want to write s shell script which can edited files in folders.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something similar?

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(find $1 -printf "%f\n")
do
    find $2 -name $i -print
done
```

And you can call it:

```
./script.sh ~/newmusics ~/oldmusics
```

Comment: I modified the script.

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but you have a wrong *parameter expansion* and a typo : `filname` vs `filename`, so :

```
#!/bin/bash

dir1="$1"
dir2="$2"
log=~/log.txt

for i in "$dir1"/*;do
    filename="${i##*/}"
    if [ ! -e "$dir2/$filename" ];then
        echo "$filename" | tee -a "$log"
    fi
done
```

Then, you can call the script like this :

```
./script.sh dir1 dir2
```